# Unity ADS не работает на реальном устройстве, однако, работает в редакторе юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня возникла проблема с воспроизведением рекламы в юнити(использую Unity ADS), в редакторе тестовая реклама мне показывается, а вот после сборки в apk реклама исчезает. Реклама должна вызываться к
Код метода "start":

```
void Start()
{
    Advertisement.Initialize("4211303", false);
}
```

Код метода, где вызывается реклама:

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
      if (collision.collider.name == "DeadZone")
        {
            MainMenu.deathtimes++;
            if (MainMenu.deathtimes % 3 == 0 && Advertisement.IsReady())
            {
                Advertisement.Show("Banner_Android");
            }
}
```

С переменной deathtimes проблем нет, ей присваивается 0 при входе в игру.

Comment: Разрешения все получены?

Comment: Какие именно разрешения?

Comment: Доступ к сети там, хранилищу, я не знаю, какие именно вам требуюься.

Comment: Да, всё это получено

Comment: `Advertisement.IsReady` вероятно возвращает `false`

Comment: Почему-то не работает реклама типа "banner", погуглив я понял, что у многих такая проблема в России и ЕС, спасибо за помощь)